Error when using epiR::epi.2by2 with grouped dataframe
According to the epiR::epi2by2 help page, you can use this function with a grouped dataframe created with dplyr::group_by. However, I get an error when using this method:
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

library(epiR)
#> Loading required package: survival
#> Package epiR 2.0.74 is loaded
#> Type help(epi.about) for summary information
#> Type browseVignettes(package = 'epiR') to learn how to use epiR for applied epidemiological analyses
#> 


df <- tibble(group = sample(c("Treatment", "Control"), 100, replace = TRUE)) |> 
  mutate(nevents = rpois(100, 1),
         time = rexp(100, 1),
         group = factor(group))

dat <- df |> 
  group_by(group) |> 
  summarise(n = sum(nevents), time = sum(time), .groups = "keep")

print(dat)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#> # Groups:   group [2]
#>   group         n  time
#>   <fct>     <int> <dbl>
#> 1 Control      34  50.0
#> 2 Treatment    50  49.2


epi.2by2(dat, method = "cohort.time")
#> Error in epi.2by2(dat, method = "cohort.time"): Column 2 (outcome) must be a factor.

Created on 2024-08-23 with reprex v2.1.0
The dataframe is grouped and in the correct format required by the function. It looks like the function expects the outcome grouping column, but that does not make sense with the cohort.time methods that uses the count of events. What's the problem here?

Yes, the error goes away, but the statistics are not computed (and it makes sense, because n is the denominator of the incidence rate, so it cannot be a factor). However, the layout of the table in the output gave me a clue, I will check if it leads to the solution. Thanks!

Looking at the output obtained using the suggestion by jpsmith, I finally understood the problem. What the function expects is a "list" version of the table, that is:

First column with group membership (has to be factor);
Second column indicating the type of information stored in the third column (has to be factor);
Third column with events and time data (has to be numeric).

I used tidyr::pivot_longer to obtain the right table:
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tidyr)
library(epiR)
#> Loading required package: survival
#> Package epiR 2.0.74 is loaded
#> Type help(epi.about) for summary information
#> Type browseVignettes(package = 'epiR') to learn how to use epiR for applied epidemiological analyses
#> 

df <- tibble(group = sample(c("Treatment", "Control"), 100, replace = TRUE)) |> 
  mutate(nevents = rpois(100, 1),
         time = rexp(100, 1),
         group = factor(group, levels = c("Treatment", "Control")))

dat <- df |> 
  group_by(group) |> 
  summarise(n = sum(nevents), time = sum(time), .groups = "keep") |> 
   pivot_longer(-group) |> 
   mutate(name = factor(name))

epi.2by2(dat, method = "cohort.time")
#>              Outcome +     Time at risk                 Inc rate *
#> Exposed +           49 41.5294155337585   117.99 (87.29 to 155.99)
#> Exposed -           51 58.3799970467432    87.36 (65.04 to 114.86)
#> Total              100 99.9094125805017   100.09 (81.44 to 121.74)
#> 
#> Point estimates and 95% CIs:
#> -------------------------------------------------------------------
#> Inc rate ratio                                 1.35 (0.89, 2.04)
#> Attrib rate in the exposed *                   30.63 (-10.19, 71.45)
#> Attrib fraction in the exposed (%)            25.96 (-11.90, 50.97)
#> Attrib rate in the population *                12.73 (-18.25, 43.71)
#> Attrib fraction in the population (%)         12.72 (5.65, 20.13)
#> -------------------------------------------------------------------
#>  Wald confidence limits
#>  CI: confidence interval
#>  * Outcomes per 100 units of population time at risk

Created on 2024-08-23 with reprex v2.1.0
